# Building 32 bit OpenSSL FIPS (nmake f ms\ntdll.mak): Illegal Character in macro

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, fips

My goal is to build the OpenSSL (openssl-1.0.2n) shared libraries (DLLs) in 32 bit with FIPS enabled. Per the procedure pescribed by openssl.org  (https://www.openssl.org/docs/fips/UserGuide-2.0.pdf), after building the FIPS canister I did:

1. perl Configure VC-WIN32 fips --with-fipslibdir=C:\usr\local\ssl\fips-2.0
2. ms\do_nasm
3. nmake ­f ms\ntdll.mak

The last (nmake f ms\ntdll.msk) throws this error:

makefile(243) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '{' in macro Stop.

Guidance? This is tricky because the OpenSSL FIPS instructions are very specific about not modifying MAKE files to stay FIPS compliant. Kind of hamstrings me.

Full listing from x86 VS2017 Command Prompt (run in admin mode):

```
**********************************************************************
** Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt v15.4.5
** Copyright (c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
**********************************************************************
[vcvarsall.bat] Environment initialized for: 'x86'

C:\Users\jlaird\source>cd C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>perl Configure VC-WIN32 fips --with-fipslibdir=C:\usr\local\ssl\fips-2.0
Configuring for VC-WIN32
    no-ec_nistp_64_gcc_128 [default]  OPENSSL_NO_EC_NISTP_64_GCC_128 (skip dir)
    no-gmp          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_GMP (skip dir)
    no-jpake        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_JPAKE (skip dir)
    no-krb5         [krb5-flavor not specified] OPENSSL_NO_KRB5
    no-libunbound   [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_LIBUNBOUND (skip dir)
    no-md2          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_MD2 (skip dir)
    no-rc5          [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RC5 (skip dir)
    no-rfc3779      [default]  OPENSSL_NO_RFC3779 (skip dir)
    no-rsax         [forced]   OPENSSL_NO_RSAX (skip dir)
    no-sctp         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SCTP (skip dir)
    no-shared       [default]
    no-ssl-trace    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL_TRACE (skip dir)
    no-ssl2         [default]  OPENSSL_NO_SSL2 (skip dir)
    no-store        [experimental] OPENSSL_NO_STORE (skip dir)
    no-unit-test    [default]  OPENSSL_NO_UNIT_TEST (skip dir)
    no-weak-ssl-ciphers [default]  OPENSSL_NO_WEAK_SSL_CIPHERS (skip dir)
    no-zlib         [default]
    no-zlib-dynamic [default]
IsMK1MF=1
CC            =cl
CFLAG         =-DOPENSSL_THREADS  -DDSO_WIN32 -W3 -WX -Gs0 -GF -Gy -nologo -DOPENSSL_SYSNAME_WIN32 -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DL_ENDIAN -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE -D_WINSOCK_DEPRECATED_NO_WARNINGS -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_PART_WORDS -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -I$(FIPSDIR)/include -DRC4_ASM -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DRMD160_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
EX_LIBS       =
CPUID_OBJ     =x86cpuid.o
BN_ASM        =bn-586.o co-586.o x86-mont.o x86-gf2m.o
EC_ASM        =
DES_ENC       =des-586.o crypt586.o
AES_ENC       =aes-586.o vpaes-x86.o aesni-x86.o
BF_ENC        =bf-586.o
CAST_ENC      =cast-586.o
RC4_ENC       =rc4-586.o
RC5_ENC       =rc5-586.o
MD5_OBJ_ASM   =md5-586.o
SHA1_OBJ_ASM  =sha1-586.o sha256-586.o sha512-586.o
RMD160_OBJ_ASM=rmd-586.o
CMLL_ENC      =cmll-x86.o
MODES_OBJ     =ghash-x86.o
ENGINES_OBJ   =
PROCESSOR     =
RANLIB        =true
ARFLAGS       =
PERL          =perl
THIRTY_TWO_BIT mode
BN_LLONG mode
RC4_INDEX mode
RC4_CHUNK is undefined

Configured for VC-WIN32.

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>ms\do_nasm

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>perl util\mkfiles.pl  1>MINFO

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>perl util\mk1mf.pl nasm VC-WIN32  1>ms\nt.mak

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>perl util\mk1mf.pl dll nasm VC-WIN32  1>ms\ntdll.mak

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>perl util\mk1mf.pl nasm BC-NT  1>ms\bcb.mak

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>perl util\mkdef.pl 32 libeay  1>ms\libeay32.def

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>perl util\mkdef.pl 32 ssleay  1>ms\ssleay32.def

C:\OpenSSL_Source\32bit\openssl-1.0.2n>nmake ­f ms\ntdll.mak

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

makefile(243) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '{' in macro
Stop.
```

Looks like this was noted in a previous version of OpenSSL on GitHub but there was no posted resolution...issue just got closed, I have no idea what to do:
https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/4352

I uploaded the ntdll.mak file to google drive here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B2GIWJjdyOXR6ycCLq8OpV4Skhg2N8ob/view?usp=sharing

Line 243 (not real helpful but here it is):

```
$(OBJ_D)\ecb3_enc.obj $(OBJ_D)\cfb64enc.obj $(OBJ_D)\cfb64ede.obj \
```

Comment: Maybe run a pre-processor to see what do all those macros expand into and analyze the code?

Comment: Not quite sure how to do that since I don't understand enough about the build process. I'll look into it. I was able to make 32 bit shared libraries (DLLs) ONCE. Then I got the same error later.

Answer (score 0):

You're just missing one tiny dash before the 'f' in the command, the exact command should be:

```
nmake -­f ms\ntdll.mak
```

By missing the dash, you're actually calling nmake on the Makefile in the top-level directory, which happens to exist but is incompatible with nmake, thus the error.

I found out because I got the same error message when trying to build OpenSSL on Windows, and in my case I was just calling nmake without any argument (as I didn't bother reading the INSTALL.W32 file first...)

Answer (score -1):

Not that this helps a lot but the offending character is in the makefile itself in the root of the OpenSSL source.  I'll paste starting at line 241:

```
    ENGINES_ASM_OBJ='$(ENGINES_ASM_OBJ)'        \
    PERLASM_SCHEME='$(PERLASM_SCHEME)'      \
    FIPSLIBDIR='${FIPSLIBDIR}'          \
    FIPSDIR='${FIPSDIR}'                \
    FIPSCANLIB="$${FIPSCANLIB:-$(FIPSCANLIB)}"  \
    THIS=$${THIS:-$@} MAKEFILE=Makefile MAKEOVERRIDES=
```

Comment: This is not an answer but rather a comment. Commenting is subject to a minimal reputation requirement, which you can find out more about here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead

Comment: @Router Gray thanks for the thought (answer or comment or whatever we wish to call it) that makes me think I may not have set the fips environmental variable right. I assumed that since the argument was in the command I didn't need to set the environment variable. Maybe the makefile requires the folder path in both places. I'll try that soon and see if that fixes the problem.